# Easier way of converting numpy datatypes to native python datatypes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of elements with different datatypes. I need to convert all `numpy.int64 numpy.float64` to `int` or `float`.

Isnt there an easier/more compact way than this:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

a = [np.float64(1.2), np.int64(123), 'blablabla', datetime.datetime.now()]
#[1.2, 123, 'blablabla', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 24, 19, 16, 2, 37112)]

a = [float(v) if isinstance(v,np.float64) else v for v in a]
a = [int(v) if isinstance(v,np.int64) else v for v in a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy.item() instead of NumPy element it will give the approximate python native type

```
a =[val.item() if type(val).__module__ == np.__name__ else val for val in a ]

for val in native:
    print(type(val))
```

```
 numpyNum = np.float(1.2)
 pythonNum = num.item()

pythonNativeTypeValues = [ v.item() for v in a]
```

When you have multiple types in your list you need to check the element type is NumPy or not so the code will be as follow

```
import numpy as np 
import datetime
a = [np.float64(1.2), np.int64(123), 'blablabla', datetime.datetime.now()]
native = []


for val in a:
    if type(val).__module__ == np.__name__:
        val =val.item()
    native.append(val)


for val in native:
    print(type(val))
#<class 'float'>
#<class 'int'>
#<class 'str'>
#<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

If you plan to use list compression the code will be one line and that is

```
native =[val.item() if type(val).__module__ == np.__name__ else val for val in a ]
```